# Issue in updating the database, using php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have this problem while updating my database, so, it all works, i mean i have the form, it prints the values, but when i try to update it, everything gets updated apart from the username and password..

Here is the code i use..

Thanks!

```
if ($Act=='Save') {     
        mysql_query("BEGIN");       
        $sql = "Insert into tbl_galleries (gal_title,gal_image,username,password) Values (";                    
        $sql.= "'". strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string(trim($gal_title))). "','". strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string(trim($gal_image))) ."','". strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string(trim($username))). "',,'". strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string(trim($password))). "',);";         
        $query = mysql_query($sql);
        if(!$query){
            mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
            $myErrorsUpGr = mysql_error();
            echo $myErrorsUpGr;
        } else {
            mysql_query("COMMIT");
            echo 'Insertion was successfull.';
        }

    } else if ($Act=='Update'){         

        mysql_query("BEGIN");

        $sql = " Update tbl_galleries set ";
        $sql.= " gal_title='" . strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string(trim($gal_title))) . "',";
        $sql.= " gal_image='" . strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string(trim($gal_image))) . "'";
        $sql.= " where gal_id=" . $gal_id . ";";
        $sql.= " username='" . strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string(trim($username))) . "',";
            $sql.= " password='" . strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string(trim($password))) . "',";
<?php
    include_once("db/envato_db.php");
    if ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']!='')
    {  
        $sql = "";        
        $sql = "SELECT gal_id,gal_title,gal_image,username,password FROM tbl_galleries where gal_id='" . $_REQUEST['gid'] ."';";
        $query = mysql_query($sql) or $myErrorsP = mysql_error();
        if(isset($myErrors) && $myErrorsP!='')
        {     

        } 
        else 
        {          
            $row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
            mysql_free_result($query);
            $gal_id    = $row[0];
            $gal_title = $row[1];
            $gal_image = $row[2];     
            $username  = $row[3];
            $password  = $row[4];                 
        } 
    }
?>
    <tr>
        <td width="104">Gallery Title:</td>
        <td width="556"><input type="text" id="gtitle" name="gtitle" class="typeText" maxlength="50" value="<?php echo isset($gal_title)? $gal_title : ""?>" tabindex="1" /></td>    
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Gallery Image:</td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" id="gimg" name="gimg" class="typeText" maxlength="100" value="<?php echo isset($gal_image)? $gal_image : ""?>" readonly/>
        <input type="file" name="gimg_upl" id="gimg_upl"/>&nbsp;
        <a href="javascript:;" onClick="ajaxFileUpload('gimg_upl','img_files');" title="Click to Upload Image" name="Click to Upload Image">Upload</a>          
        </td>    
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="104">Username:</td>
        <td width="556"><input type="text" id="gusername" name="gusername" class="typeText" maxlength="50" value="<?php echo isset($username)? $username : ""?>" tabindex="1" /></td>    
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td width="104">Password:</td>
        <td width="556"><input type="text" id="gpassword" name="gpassword" class="typeText" maxlength="50" value="<?php echo isset($password)? $password : ""?>" tabindex="1" /></td>    
    </tr>       
    </table> 

    <table id="savetbl" style="width:680px;" cellpadding="3">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="2">
    <?php 
        if(isset($gal_id) && $gal_id!='')
        {                
            if(!isset($myErrorsP)) 
            { 
                ?>
                <input type="button" value="&raquo; Update &laquo;" class="but" name="button" alt="Update" title="Update" onClick="Do_Update('Update', '<?php echo $gal_id?>');" tabindex="3">                                         
                <?php 
            } 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            if(!isset($myErrorsP)) 
            { 
                ?>
                <input type="button" value="&raquo; Save &laquo;" class="but" name="button" alt="Save" title="Save" onClick="Do_Update('Save','0');" tabindex="3">                  
                <?php 
            } 
        } 
        ?>               
        </td>    
    </tr>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't use the `mysql_*` functions, they are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you want to learn, [here is a good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: isn't this part supposed to do it?  <input type="button" value="&raquo; Save &laquo;" class="but" name="button" alt="Save" title="Save" onClick="Do_Update('Save','0');" tabindex="3">

Comment: Where is the `update` in this code?

Comment: You need to write sql **UPDATE** query to actually update the data. Where is your update query?

Comment: This code is used to update the database... id don't know.. it worked like this before i inserted a username and password..

Comment: There is a Do_update function here...

Comment: This code has no Insert query either, it just has a select query!

Comment: `Do_update` is javascript function (if defined), not php!

Comment: It may have something to do with : Do_Update('Save','0') and tabindexes.. because this code works like this, i mean there is no input file besides envatodb.php which itself holds nothing important..

Comment: @Al12 Do_update is a javascript function. I am afraid you are not clear with basics. Start learning basic SQL http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_intro.asp

Comment: Well, if it was in pure sql i would be clear i guess, i know what a update query is, i just need to edit this code over here, in order not to change everything, that's why i asked!

Comment: typo: $myErrors != $myErrorsP

Comment: Hey thanks, i've updated the code , can you plese check it?...

Comment: @Al12: this line:         if(isset($myErrors) && $myErrorsP!='') is not right. You don't set $myErrors, so it will never evaluate true

Answer (score 0):

On your code you have this :

```
$sql.= " where gal_id=" . $gal_id . ";";
$sql.= " username='" . strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string(trim($username))) . "',";
$sql.= " password='" . strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string(trim($password))) . "',";
```

Try to set the where clause after the update of username & password :

```
$sql.= " username='" . strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string(trim($username))) . "',";
$sql.= " password='" . strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string(trim($password))) . "'";
$sql.= " where gal_id=" . $gal_id . ";";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$sql.= " where gal_id=" . $gal_id . ";";
$sql.= "AND username='" . strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string(trim($username))) . "',";
$sql.= "AND password='" . strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string(trim($password))) . "',";
```

Lines 22, 23, and 24 of your sample code

Comment: Hey thanks... but besides this i have a problem with insertion! not just updating..

Comment: Line 4 in your sample code you have a double comma (i.e. ,,) in between the $username and $password values. I think this may be your problem.

Comment: Also, remove the comma before the last closing bracket in your INSERT statement.